# two ansible sesu become task generate error

Tags: ansible

i create a playbook where i need to execute tasks with sesu become method , but a get an error , ansible claims that the sesu escalate previleges not exist when he reach the second task where i use sesu.

The task : Add custom properties end whell and finish without any error.

The task Add shared libraries generate error , the error is that the 'sesu' escalate privileges is not reconized:

```
- name: Add custom properties
  become_user: was_user
  become: true
  become_method: sesu
  become_flags: '-'
  shell: "addCustomProperties.py {{item.path}}"
  with_items: "{{ customProperties_find.files |sort(attribute='path') }}"
  loop_control:
    label: '{{ item.path }}'

- name: Find addSharedLibrary config files
  find:
    paths: "addSharedLibrary"
    patterns: "*.properties"
  register: addSharedLibrary_find

- name: Add shared libraries
  become_user: was_user
  become: true
  become_method: sesu
  become_flags: '-'
  shell: "addSharedLibrary.py {{item.path}}"
  #with_items: "{{ addSharedLibrary_find.files }}"
  with_items: "{{ addSharedLibrary_find.files |sort(attribute='path') }}"
  loop_control:
    label: '{{ item.path }}'
```

any idea please ?

Comment: This module is new to version 2.8. Which ansible version are you using?

Comment: ansible 2.8.2 , i have checked , the become plugin  exist

Comment: Did you run the playbook with `-vvv` ? Any valuable info you get in there ? It's hard to help with only the info "option is not recognized". What is the exact error your get ?(share the trace of the play)